# Approximation of e^x using Maclaurin Series in Python

Tags: python, series, expansion, exponential

I'm trying to approximate e^x using the Maclaurin series in a function called `my_exp(x)`, I believe everything I've done so far is right but I'm getting incorrect approximations for whatever number I try.

```
import math
for i in range (x):
    exp = 1 + ((x**i)/math.factorial(i))
print(exp)
```

For example, whenever I try `my_exp(12)` I get 18614.926233766233 instead of 162754.79141900392
Help?

Comment: You aren't actually adding up the sum - your printed output is the last term in the series. Also the code you have posted doesn't seem to correspond to what you say you're calling - where is the definition of `my_exp()`?

Comment: The whole code has the `def my_exp(x)` in it I just included the guts of the function

Comment: Your `import` is *inside* the function?! Please see [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Comment: In terms of approximating infinite series, you might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23216920/3001761) of mine helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the e^x series is an infinite series, and so it makes no sense to only sum the first x terms of the series.

```
def myexp(x):
  e=0
  for i in range(0,100): #Sum the first 100 terms of the series
    e=e+(x**i)/math.factorial(i)
  return e
```

You can also define the precision of your result and get a better solution.

```
def myexp(x):
    e=0
    pres=0.0001
    s=1
    i=1
    while s>pres:
        e=e+s
        s=(x**i)/math.factorial(i)
        i=i+1
    return e
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to accumulate the terms of the series, you need to replace the assignment to `exp` with a line such as:

```
exp = exp + ((x**i)/math.factorial(i))
```

Comment: I've added this to the code but it's still giving me an incorrect answer

Comment: @vanaghka Another thing is that `range (x)` does not make particular sense as the set of values of `i` that you are interested in. Why stop at i=0 when computing `my_exp(1)`? Is it really necessary to use 1000 terms when computing `my_exp(1000)`?