# Evaluating definite integral of Maclaurin series from 0 to 1

Tags: python, integration

I wanted to know if there is a way of evaluating the definite integral of a Maclaurin series for the first 6 terms from 0 to 1. The function which I am supposed to use is `e^(-x)`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you just want the value, consider https://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Approximation of e^x using Maclaurin Series in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24915194/approximation-of-ex-using-maclaurin-series-in-python)

Comment: Since the first six terms of a Maclaurin series is a polynomial, you seem to be asking if there is a way to evaluate the definite integral of a polynomial. Yes, it is possible to evaluate the definite integral of a polynomial. Given the simple nature of this particular polynomial, you don't even need any special tool such as `sympy`, though importing `math` to get the factorial might help. In any event, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: That's actually my question. How do I do it manually. I currently have no solution.

Comment: When integrating from 0 to 1, the definite integral is just the sum of the coefficients of the antiderivative (taken with C = 0). Are you uncertain how to find the antiderivative of a polynomial? If so, a few seconds of google should solve that. In any event, if that is your question then this really isn't a programming problem at all and might be a better fit on [mathematics.se]

Comment: As a hint, the antiderivative of `x^n/n!` is `x^(n+1)/[(n+1)*n!]` which is the same as `x^(n+1)/(n+1)!`. The antiderivative of the Maclaurin series is just the sum of some reciprocals of factorials.